# How to use Promises.all and async/await

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm using Botpress to work on this thing but I'm making some fundamental Javascript error because I'm trying to combine Promises and Await/Async. Any help on how to correct this would be amazing

This is my code

```
const knex = await bp.db.get();
const userIds = await knex('_students').distinct('id').pluck('id');
return Promise.all(
  userIds.map((userId) => {
     return await bp.dialogEngine.jumpTo(userId, 'question.flow.json')
    }
  )
);
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

How do I make code work with that await in the return statement because I need that as per Botpress API

Comment: If `.jumpTo` returns a `Promise` already (which it sounds like it is, if you're trying to `await` it), you can just use that `Promise`, no `await` (nor `async`) needed, just map to an array of those Promises

Answer (score 1):

You can add `async` as follow:

```
async (userid) => {...}`
^
```

However, you can use the `Promise` directly from `jumpTo(...)` and then return the `Promise.all(...)`

```
const knex = await bp.db.get();
const userIds = await knex('_students').distinct('id').pluck('id');

const promises = userIds.map((userId) => {
  return bp.dialogEngine.jumpTo(userId, 'question.flow.json')
});

return Promise.all(promises);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `await` here:

```
const knex = await bp.db.get();
const userIds = await knex('_students').distinct('id').pluck('id');
return Promise.all(
  userIds.map((userId) => {
     return bp.dialogEngine.jumpTo(userId, 'question.flow.json')
    }
  )
);
```

Just return an array of promises and you will get a resolved value in the array resolved from `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 0):

await is valid or you can use with only async function. And remember that async always return a promise and await solve this promise and extract the values. For that, you need to wrap your code inside the async function like

```
const async_await_promise = async function(){
    const knex = await bp.db.get();
    const userIds = await knex('_students').distinct('id').pluck('id');
    return await Promise.all(
         userIds.map((userId) => {
         return await bp.dialogEngine.jumpTo(userId, 'question.flow.json')
    }))
}
async_await_promise ();
```